# WSDL.exe - generate interface as well as concrete class for easy fake/mocks later

Tags: .net, testing, soap, mocking, wsdl.exe

Is it possible to get WSDL.exe to generate interfaces as well as, or instead of, concrete classes when it generates proxys to a web service?

We're consuming a 3rd party webservice from an ASP.Net application, and have generated our proxy classes using WSDL.exe all well and good.

I now want to write tests against my wrapper and business classes by faking out the web service. There is no interface or abstract base class to the proxy, and they are marked internal, meaning I can't inherit from them without putting my Fake/mock test code into my business project/assemblies.

I could manually create an interface (using resharper) and edit the class, however if the 3rd part change their WSDL/web service I or my successors will have to also manually edit the interface, and automatically generated classes, which never seems like a good idea.

What's the most elegant way to fake or mock this service? Should I put the fake in the business project? Should I manually edit the files and create an interface? Should I do something completely different?

Comment: Note that WCF does not have this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right, prompted by Philip's answer I set off on one, and may have come up with a working solution. Using WSDL.exe I generated the interfaces (using the /si switch) **and** normal proxy classes, and added both to my business project.

I then created a new class which inherits from the concrete class AND implements the interface. This little class contained basically no code, as the inherited concrete members provided an implicit implementation of the interface members. The code compiled first time and I've been able to substitute this little "shim" (?adaptor?) class into my integration tests, and execute calls against the live 3rd party server.

I can now create other classes (mocks or fakes) which implement the interface, and substitue them instead of the "shim" class.

**Edit:**
OK, I've worked a little further on this, and barring a few complications it's working.

The first significant issue is that the proxy classes are still marked "internal", so the derived (adaptor/shim) class has to be internal too. This isn't a problem if you put a Factory class into your business project/assembly which new's up the proxy classes, and returns them as the interface.

The second issue I found was that we were setting the URL and timeout properties of the webserice explicitly, but these are not included in the interface instead they are inherited from System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol via SoapHttpClientProtocol. Again, I dealt with this in the factory, as it's an implementation detail that I'm happy isn't in the interface.

Edit: 
This is still working out prety well for me while testing and developing our Facade. Since getting the proxy behind an interface I've also created a logging decorator class, which is capturing loads of example calls for use debugging, and when the 3rd party server is offline.

I've written up what I did in a little more detail here: http://www.flowerchild.org.uk/archive/2010/09/21/mocking-or-faking-or-maybe-stubbing-a-wsdl-exe-soap.html

Comment: +1 This answer is great. I did the same thing as you describe, but I had the problem that I had to edit the generated proxy code.  Because it includes types which are also defined in the interface. How did you manage to avoid this?

Comment: Link is broken.  New link: http://www.flowerchild.org.uk/archive/2010/09/21/mocking-or-faking-or-maybe-stubbing-a-wsdl-exe-soap.html

Comment: Thanks @Bobson - link updated. Although I'll take this opportunity to point out for anyone reading, that this was years ago, and probably doesn't represent the best practice today.

Comment: @AndrewM - Yeah, I discovered after finding this answer that WSDL.exe is generally discouraged these days, but svcutil.exe doesn't support an equivalent switch.

Answer (score 4):

You can run wsdl with the `/serverinterface` or `/si` switch to get interfaces for each binding in the wsdl.  This is meant to give you the server-side skeleton from a wsdl document, but the interfaces should get you on your way - if I understand the question correctly.

**EDIT** -- After reading the comment, I believe that I misunderstood the question - you want client interface/concrete so that you can code to contract not implementation.  The `/si` switch will probably not give you what you want at all.

I'm not aware of any switch that can give you this behavior, as wsdl basically creates one of three things:  1) client proxy classes: 2) server abstract classes (for creating a server implementation)  3) server interfaces (again, for creating a server implementation - this is just iface instead of abstract class)   I don't see any way to force the client proxy classes to implement interfaces (other than INotifyPropertyChanged on data types)

Comment: Thanks Philip, Does it also generate the proxy classes, implementing that interface? Edit: Ie, I only want to write my fake, I still need the real proxy classes too.

Comment: I've just tried it, with the /si flag, and I get the interface only, no implementation. I'll keep investigating though.

Comment: See my edit - I'm afraid you may have to write a post-wsdl transform tool, or find another approach to do what you want.

Comment: Hi Philip, thanks for the update, that confirms what I just found when I started experimenting with the /si switch. However I think I've found a possible work around, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I've always found that these generated classes are too large to mock easily (too many methods / property).

Rather, create a Facade or Repository that implements just the calls you need, and passes back DTO style objects with just the properties you care about.

Write some simple integration tests against the real Webservice, and then mock the simpler Facade in the rest of the tests.

An added benefit of this approach is that you effectively get an anticorruption layer, so changes to the 3rd party will only impact a small area of your code.

Comment: Hi David, Good point, but it's the Facade I'm trying to test. The service we're consuming is the cause, it uses lots of embedded XML, the Facade uses objects, but I need to ensure that the calls the Facade makes to the service are serialised to XML that validates against the provided schemas, hence mocking out the service. While the proxy and interfaces are a bit huge, I can leave the VS/Resharper stubbs in place for all but the interesting methods, so it's not too much work. possibly our Facade isn't really a facade because it contains translation logic.