# Mocking a web service with SoupUI and using this in Visual Studyo

Tags: web-services, mocking, soapui

I want to use a mocked service in an enterprise project. So can I use Visual Studio to fetch data, get response from mocked service, when I have no connection to the actual service?

When I try this I get the error, "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Or  are you have another suggestion

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

[This question might have the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744602/soapui-with-fiddler)
Quote:

> Try File > Preferences > Proxy Settings Host 127.0.0.1 Port 8888
>
> and use http://localhost./myservice/myservice.asmx

On the "another suggestion" front...

I had a similar requirement ([discussed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717082/wsdl-exe-generate-interface-as-well-as-concrete-class-for-easy-fake-mocks-later)) And chose not to use SOAPUI, but to get the service behind an interface, then use the real service as one implementation, and a mock service, which implements the same interface, as mock.

I wrote a [blog post about how I did it here](http://www.flowerchild.org.uk/blog/archive/2010/09/22/mocking-or-faking-or-maybe-stubbing-a-wsdl-exe-soap.aspx)